# why "too many open file" error occured here

Tags: java, iostream

In my Java Application, I have around 30 Java files which have ObjectOutputStreams and ObjectInputStreams. but I never close those streams in anywhere. 
The application is working fine for some time, after a week or so, I am getting too many files open error. Is this because of not closing the streams or anything else?

Please help me out in better understanding the issue....

Comment: You should `close()` if it is not used , perhaps the OS reached its limits on open files !

Answer (score 1):

Any stream has to be CLOSED after usage in a try catch / with fianlly(to close here) or try-with-resources, for being sure it  gets closed since it implements Closable interface.
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8

```
  try {
      // open stream
      // use stream

    } catch(IOException e) {
      // handle exceptions
    }
    finally{
      // try-catch closing( for multiple clsoes mainly)
    }
```